# Reference about the affect of the change of boundary to the eigenvalue of Laplacian

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, elliptic-operators

In my view , it is hard to know how the principl eigenvalue exchange when boundary change. For example , when we deform the boundary under some geometric flow, how to change the eigenvalue of Laplacian ? I fail to find relevant paper.

Comment: By "the" eigenvalue you mean the smallest eigenvalue or the whole sequence of eigenvalues?

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz   It is the positive smallest eigenvalue. I miss it.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Maybe, Soufi's **Domain deformations and eigenvalues of the Dirichlet Laplacian in a Riemannian manifold**  is a suitable reference, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/1889593_Domain_deformations_and_eigenvalues_of_the_Dirichlet_Laplacian_in_a_Riemannian_manifold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing I can say is that it changes continuously when the domain is smoothly deformed.

Recall that the smallest eigenvalue of $-\Delta$ with zero boundary conditions can be described as the reciprocal of the optimal constant in Poincare's inequality, i.e. 
$$ \lambda(\Omega) = \inf \frac{\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2}{\int_\Omega |u|^2}, $$
where the infimum is taken over all nonzero functions $u \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ or equivalently $u \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$.

Say there is a diffeomorphism $X \ni x \mapsto y \in Y$ with bi-Lipschitz constant $L \geqslant 1$. If two functions $u,v$ are related by $v(x) = u(y(x))$, then 
\begin{align}
\int_X |\nabla v(x)|^2 dx 
& = \int_X \left|\nabla u(y(x)) \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}\right|^2 dx \\
& \leqslant L^2 \int_Y |\nabla u(y)|^2 \left|\det \frac{dx}{dy}\right| dy \\
& \leqslant L^{n+2} \int_Y |\nabla u(y)|^2 dy, 
\end{align}
similarly 
$$ \int_X |v(x)|^2 dx \geqslant L^{-n} \int_Y |u(y)|^2 dy. $$

This shows that $\lambda(X) \leqslant L^{2n+2} \lambda(Y)$; for the same reason $\lambda(X) \geqslant L^{-2n-2} \lambda(Y)$. If you deform your domain $\Omega$ by a group of diffeomorphisms $\Phi_t$, the bi-Lipschitz constant of $\Phi_t$ is close to $1$ for small $t$, so $\lambda(\Phi_t(\Omega))$ is continuous in $t$.